# PHP Rounding when using number_format() in a formula give an occasional wrong result

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have to write a file that contains a 'price including tax', the 'price excluding tax', and the 'tax'. The only figure I have to work with is the price including tax and the output needs to be to 2 decimal places. Writing the data to the file is not a problem.

The output file is sent to a remote processing system that is not in my control.

The remote processing system does some checking and adds 'price excluding tax' to 'tax' and checks the value against 'price including tax'.

Most values work OK, however a 'price including tax' of 35.37 or 31.17 (plus some other values) causes a problem as the number_format() rounds up 'price excluding tax' & 'tax' and then when totalled = 35.58 or 31.18.

How can I either use number_format() and get the correct result every time and output to 2 decimal places or what other solution could be used to achieve what is needed?
The code below shows output to screen for testing purposes.

```
$taxRate = 20;
$priceIncTax = 35.37;
$priceExTax = $priceIncTax / (1 + ($taxRate / 100));
$priceTax = $priceIncTax - $priceExTax;

echo 'PRICE_EXCLUDING_TAX: ' . number_format($priceExTax,2).'<br>';
echo 'PRICE_TAX: ' . number_format($priceTax,2).'<br>';
echo 'PRICE_INCLUDING_TAX: ' . number_format($priceIncTax,2).'<br>';
echo 'PRICE_AFTER_TAX + PRICE_TAX: ' . (number_format($priceExTax,2) + number_format($priceTax,2)) .'<br>';
```

Comment: What is the output of that code, and what is the expected output?  And why are there smart quotes in it?

Comment: This isn't a number_format problem. This is a rounding problem.

Comment: Rounding is, by definition, a lossy operation - that is, you cannot both round a number and retain its accuracy. As soon as you apply any kind of rounding, you are saying "the number is approximately this" not "the number is exactly this".

Comment: The way rounding works isn't really intuitive since we were taught *wrong* back in the school days. To cut long story short, there are 3 rounding methods - round up, round down, cut-off. What we were taught in school that if decimal ends with 5, we can round up to next significant digit, which is not entirely accurate. `number_format` will use different approach, and if you want to stick with what's intuitive to you - you need `round($number, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`. Then use formatting functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The smart quotes came from creating the post in Word first and then pasting it. Sorry I didn't notice them and thanks to ithcy for fixing them. After rethinking the problem I'm just going to check the $priceIncTax against the calculated total and if it's different adjust either the tax or excluding tax value. I think it will only ever be out by 0.01 anyway.